# twig path syntax for multiple variables

Tags: symfony, path, twig

Does anyone know the correct syntaxe for a path (in twig) with multiple variables.

I know how to do it for just one variable but for more than one cannot find any syntax explanation/document.

Here for one variable: (but I would like more that one... like variable1_name = article_id and variable2_name = language)

```
  <li><a href="{{ path('RouteName', {'variable1_name': variable1_value}) }}"></a></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List them with commas in between:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('RouteName', {'variable1_name': variable1_value, 'variable2_name': variable2_value, 'variable3_name': variable3_value}) }}"></a></li>
```

Comment: ok thanks dmnptr. It works fine indeed. DO you know a good website where the syntaxe for symfony and twig is explained. I couldn't find much about it. even it was not to dificult to find an answer.

Comment: My primary source is the official Symfony docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html.